# I crossthreaded the bike frame using force on the BB. Can still be saved?

Tags: bottom-bracket, cross-thread, threaded-bottom-bracket

I have a MTB, with "normal" square taper BB, and a 3 chainring crankset from Shimano.

After some problems with my pedals, I managed to destroy the fillet on the crank arms too and in the end I bought new crank set + pedals.

On the right side, where the BB is screwing in the frame, I wasn’t able to screw it by hand freely even after 10 minutes of tries. Because I had a huge wrench, I went all the way and forced it to 95%.

Now, there is a misalignment between BB and the frame, it doesn’t stay parallel with frame (I will attach some photos), and my front gears won’t shift on the 3rd gear because they are now too far away from the frame.

If I add something like a spacer in the gear changer, can this be saved and be able to shift on all 3 gears?

---

https://i.imgur.com/79NqcH1.mp4

As you can see in the above video, in the upper part (actually down), the distance is very small, while on one side is bigger, because of crossthreading.

---

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Images from https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yoTM.jpg

Comment: Go to a bike shop and let them re-cut the threads. Keep in mind that for bottom brackets the non-drive side (left side) is *right threaded* while the drive side is *left threaded* i.e. tightens counter-clockwise. For pedal threads it’s exactly the other way around.

Comment: To clarify, a press-fit BB does not have any threads to cross-thread. You've probably got a British/ISO BB.

Comment: Now you know: big wrench is bad for bikes. Please ask a question like this BEFORE you break your bike!!

Comment: Sorry, actually it looks exactly like this: https://images.bike24.net/media/720/i/mb/d3/d0/42/16326-00-d-25483.jpg so I think press-fit is not the right term. But somehow I got the two parts out when I forcely took out the bb because crank set on the right side wouldn't want to come off. So maybe when inserting the right thread back onto the BB, I didn't matched them as they were before, that's why the cross-threading happened :(

Comment: I think it's possible it's not cross threaded, that little bit of difference could also just be lack of frame chasing. Can you verify the BB spindle is off axis?

Comment: I was thinking that in the happy case, let's say.. I did screw the left BB cup too much, and that's why the right side didn't go all the way inside along with the BB. But now I am not so eager to take out left side again and test as I have developed a cross-thread phobia lol. Regarding BB spindle idk if it's off axis, I checked visually and it seems  the pedals are going the correct direction, not left or right, or not as much as I can tell with the bare eye

Comment: Were you able to thread it in partway by hand and then had to send it, or did you have to crank on it pretty much the entire way?

Comment: 20% went by hand and then only using full force until those 95%

Answer (score 6):

If the threads can be re-cut, as Michael suggests in the comments, try that first.

If not, there are "rescue" bottom brackets that do not thread into the bottom-bracket shell; instead, they have two halves that screw together from opposite sides and brace against the outside edges of the shell.

Comment: The aforementioned “rescue” BBs appear to be called threadless BBs. The downside is that they are only available for JIS square tapers and may not be available in all lengths, but they could work. Another option is that the shop *may* be willing to re-tap the shell to Italian thread, but then you’re stuck with Italian threaded BBs.

Comment: They also exist for Hollowtech 2: https://custom-junkies.com/threadless-external-repair-bottom-bracket-yst-bb-0901

Comment: That's a good idea, didn't knew that this rescue solution exists! Will search for them in my local shop. And my BB is square taper so no problem with that, thanks

Comment: @WeiwenNg's point is that there's more than one [square-taper standard](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/bbtaper.html).

Comment: actually, my point was also that I thought those BBs were only made for JIS. For some reason, I hadn't bothered to check! Anyway, JIS is by far the more common square taper standard. Does anyone know of any MTB cranks that use ISO other than Campagnolo, which only ever made one MTB group for a short time?

Comment: @WeiwenNg Yes in a sense; in the early days of MTB, some of the first triples employed were TA and Stronglight, which use ISO (or some of them do).

Comment: The tap set to recut these threads is priced beyond the home workshop.  OP will need a bike shop to do this task.

Answer (score 6):

The shifting problems are separate from the bottom bracket and frame problems. You've got a new crank installed, so it would be expected that the front derailleur and shifter will have to be completely re-adjusted. That means adjusting the FD clamp height and angle, the limit screws, and the cable tension, in that order. Hopefully the crank you chose is a good match with the existing FD and shifter.

Your shell can probably be rescued, but what will be needed isn't clear from the picture. Unfortunately it looks like the cross-threaded cup is steel and the frame is aluminum, which is the combination most likely to result in damage to the frame threads. If I'm wrong and the cup is plastic, then the frame threads are probably less affected if at all, and the cup will be the part with the new set of misaligned threads cut into it.

The core skill of dealing with BB shells that want to crossthread, or of fixing ones that have been cross threaded, is discerning when the cup (or the tap, or the cup you're using as an improvised tap) is starting correctly with its first thread engaging into the proper first thread of the shell. Sight and feel can both come into play. In some cases it's helpful to get everything clean and then externally mark on the parts where each thread begins. In some cases it's helpful to use a pick, knife-edged riffler file, or screwdriver to very slightly open up the damaged threads. Then you're very carefully going in and turning the cup or tap the wrong direction until you feel the click where the openings of the threads want to begin interfacing. Get the click, begin turning it in, make sure everything seems to be aligned right, and then carefully begin using some force on it to undo the damage. In some cases this can be done using the actual BB cup, but sometimes a piloted tap set is the only tool that will work. If that's out of reach and an improvised solution is required, you can get an old high-quality (it needs to be very hard steel) cup and cone BB cup, carefully hacksaw some channels into it to clear chips, and use that as a tap.

Comment: I ordered exactly the same size crankset, same number of tooth, same size etc, that's why I thought I don't have to set anything. Anyway I tried quick to pull the cable more and adjust it to see if I save it but didn't work. Will try also in that order as you said, actually will look up for a tutorial and do it. 
I think the cup is steel, you're right, I'd wish they are plastic.  and regarding correcting the threads, that will be a time consuming job and I'll try that one day as I have 4 diff shaped sharped picks. Will look to buy a tap set as it's good to have it in my garage for future work

Comment: btw, if I bring my bike up inside the house and work on it, will the metallic parts be "softer" because of higher temperatures? (in my garage are around 5 degrees C, while inside the house 24 Celsius)

Comment: @Jack You need a 100C+ difference to matter, not 20C, and that's for aluminum.

Comment: @Jack Even replacing a crank and bottom bracket when the new ones are identical on paper (same tooth counts, same nominal chainline), you'd still expect to at least need to make some limit screw and cable tension adjustments in order for shifting to work right. As ZOMVID points out, steel and aluminum basically don't care about temperature differences that small, although in some cases it's true that one can get things unstuck by playing on their different rates of thermal expansion/contraction.